# Does this email mean that I have been granted the visa?

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I received the following email this morning. Does it mean that my visa has been granted?

> UK Visas & Immigration has now assessed your UK visa application and made a decision. Your documents and the decision will be sent back to either the UK Visa Application Centre where you applied, where we will contact you by email over the next few days to collect them, or if you are using the courier return service, will be sent directly back to the address provided.
>
> Please note that TLScontact does not know the outcome of the assessment and has played no role in the decision-making process.
>
> Kind regards,
> TLScontact
> UK VIsas & Immigration

Comment: It means that the decision will be sent back to either the UK Visa Application Centre where you applied, where they will contact you by email over the next few days to collect them, or if you are using the courier return service, it will be sent directly back to the address you provided.

Comment: This seems to be about understanding the content of an email. Maybe this question would be a better fit at [ell.se], as the correct answer is actually right there in the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is clearly stated in the question.  It is not about travel but about understanding English.

Comment: @Cindy Just a quick-side note: At least in the US, "official" news will usually not come in an email, because it is not a very reliable or robust way to communicate. Email are as public as postal cards, and it is too easy to create fake email.

Comment: I don't see this as a language question. Imagine some country where a governmental agency issuing visas only send responds from any kind to people whose visas are granted and never contacts those whose visas have been denied. Then the existence of a mail, no matter the content, would have been an indication of acceptance. It would be a terrible, inefficient and not constructive way to run a bureaucracy, but there are enough places in the world where bureaucracies use ridiculous processes. So, the answer depends on knowing the process of visa confirmation and not on language.

Comment: @rumtscho That seems to be a completely hypothetical situation and it involves the organization lying when it claims not to know the outcome. If we believe the organization habitually lies, we can't answer the question anyway. In any case, we're looking for "questions based on _actual problems that you face_" (from [help centre](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask); emphasis mine), not hypothetical situations.

Comment: @DavidRicherby they would not be lying. They would just have a process which "swallows" rejections. Nothing strange about it, many agencies around the world work that way. Now, maybe this is unthinkable from a UK agency, but a foreigner wouldn't know that.

Comment: @rumtscho The letter explicitly says they don't know if the application was successful or not. If replies are only sent to successful applicants, then that claim would be a lie: the agency would know that the application was successful because only successful applications receive replies.

Comment: @DavidRicherby if your definition of lie includes not only "untruth uttered with malicious intent" but "untruth uttered because the utterer was too disorganized to realize it's not true" then yes, it is a lie. But in that case, most governmental agencies tend to lie. And because these lies can occur in predictable patterns, it's not very strange for such writings to signal something other than the literal words on the paper. So we could understand this question "does this letter only tell me whatever is written on it, or is it a sign for something more" which is not a language problem.

Answer (score 46):

No, it does not mean your application was successful.  Also it does not mean your application was refused.  It means neither.  It is simply an advisory that they have reached a decision and are letting you know that you will be contacted to collect your stuff from the VFS/VAC.  It is a standard email sent out automatically by UKVI whenever they update the system.

They do not like to give out results via email because they see visa decisions as private beyond what email provides.

To find out if you were successful you should examine what you get back. If your passport has a bright shiny entry clearance, you were successful. If your passport has a refusal stamp along with a refusal notice, well...  If you have been refused and you do not understand why, the odds are really good we have covered it in the site's archives. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-refusal

Comment: +1, especially for mentioning the reason they don't give out the answer by email.

Answer (score 18):

In the email they say that they themselves don't know the outcome of the assessment, so the answer to your question must be "no, it doesn't mean either that you've been granted the visa or that you haven't been granted the visa".