# Your visa application has been concluded - what does this mean?

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I got two mails from the UK embassy in Abu, saying your visa application has been concluded. I'm really confused, did I get the visa or not? What could the possible results be?

Comment: No one will  know until you get your passport. Both outcomes are possible.

Comment: Nowadays who got this type of mail thats mean visa is refuse

Comment: That’s just rumour.

Comment: I attached may world cup ticket mail afyer that y they will refuse

Comment: Sorry, but what do you expect from the answers? Whatever could be said here, it will have no influence on the result of your visa application. Just wait for your papers and you will know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does this email mean that I have been granted the visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81555/does-this-email-mean-that-i-have-been-granted-the-visa)

Answer (score 5):

The email means that they have finished processing your application. It does not tell you if your application has been accepted or refused. You will have to wait for the mailed reply which will tell you the result.

Comment: Mean i hv chance for getting visa