# Cannot find the decision made as indicated in the email and the passport has also not yet been returned

Tags: uk

Email from TLScontact states that decision has been made and sent directly to my email however, I haven't seen the email nor received the passport.   Any one who has ever received a similar email and how they retrieved the UKVI email?

Dear Customer,
TLScontact was notified by UKVI that a decision related to your visa application has been made and communicated directly to you by email.
As soon as your passport is ready to be returned, you will receive another email about the collection or the delivery procedure.
You can track the progress of your visa application by connecting to your account or by using our Track My Application app.

Comment: Have you checked as suggested by connecting to your account, or by using the Track My Application app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does this email mean that I have been granted the visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81555/does-this-email-mean-that-i-have-been-granted-the-visa)